# display submitted variable - where does it originate

Tags: nodes

The following code appears in node.tpl.php and file_entity.tpl.php, but strangely enough not in comment.tpl.php.

```
  <?php if ($display_submitted): ?>
    <div class="submitted">
      <?php print $submitted; ?>
    </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

In node.tpl.php $display_submitted it true, but in file_entity.tpl.php it is false. I am using Zen 5.x theme.

Why is it different? I would assume it is some theme setting but I can't find it.

Where is this variable initialized? And do I just set it to true in preprocess_file_entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$display_submitted is the author and date information of a node / file entity.

If you go to the node type page (e.g. admin/structure/types/manage/article) you can manage the display of it in the 'Display settings' vertical tab (see First Step in this [blog post](http://highrockmedia.com/blog/theming-node-post-date-drupal-7))

Comment: Ah, of course! Problem though as I don't see it in File Type which has no display settings vertical tab. And that is why it is false in file_entity.tpl.php.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, I have added a [patch](https://www.drupal.org/node/2356135#comment-9245529) to [File Admin](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_admin)'s issue queue. Patch adds the vertical tab to file entity's GUI edit page and sets the variable: `'file_submitted_' . $file_type`, which is read by `template_preprocess_file_entity` in `file_entity.module`.